# Sorting an array depending on different values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Lets say you have an array of days and openinghours for a shop like this:

```
Array
(
    [monday] => Array
        (
            [day] => Monday
            [isopen] => true
            [open] => 10:00
            [close] => 17:00
        )

    [tuesday] => Array
        (
            [day] => Tuesday
            [isopen] => true
            [open] => 10:00
            [close] => 17:00
        )

    [wednesday] => Array
        (
            [day] => Wednesday
            [isopen] => true
            [open] => 10:00
            [close] => 17:00
        )

    [thursday] => Array
        (
            [day] => Thursday
            [isopen] => true
            [open] => 10:00
            [close] => 17:00
        )

    [friday] => Array
        (
            [day] => Friday
            [isopen] => true
            [open] => 10:00
            [close] => 17:00
        )

    [saturday] => Array
        (
            [day] => Saturday
            [isopen] => false
            [open] => 11:00
            [close] => 14:00
        )

    [sunday] => Array
        (
            [day] => Sunday
            [isopen] => false
            [open] => 01:00
            [close] => 01:00
        )

)
```

now, i want to sort these babies like this:

```
monday - friday: 10:00-17:00
saturday-sunday: closed
```

lest say wednesday was closing 16:00 i would like this output:

```
monday-tuesday: 10:00-17:00
wednesday: 10:00-16:00
thursday-friday: 10:00-17:00
saturday-sunday: closed
```

That is, I want to sort them but still keep the order from top to bottom as the primary sorting. So, how would you do it? Loop them all and keep hours in memory and compare days is one option but is'nt there any nicer solution?

EDIT:
An actual array was requested, here it is:

```
$days = array(
            'monday' => array(
                    'day' => 'Monday',
                    'isopen' => true,
                    'open' => '10:00',
                    'close' => '17:00',
                ),
            'tuesday' => array(
                    'day' => 'Tuesday',
                    'isopen' => true,
                    'open' => '10:00',
                    'close' => '17:00',
                ),
            'wednesday' => array(
                    'day' => 'Wednesday',
                    'isopen' => true,
                    'open' => '10:00',
                    'close' => '17:00',
                ),
            'thursday' => array(
                    'day' => 'Thursday',
                    'isopen' => true,
                    'open' => '10:00',
                    'close' => '17:00',
                ),
            'friday' => array(
                    'day' => 'Friday',
                    'isopen' => true,
                    'open' => '10:00',
                    'close' => '17:00',
                ),
            'saturday' => array(
                    'day' => 'Saturday',
                    'isopen' => false,
                    'open' => '10:00', //Not used since isopen = false
                    'close' => '17:00', //Not used since isopen = false
                ),
            'sunday' => array(
                    'day' => 'Sunday',
                    'isopen' => false,
                    'open' => '10:00', //Not used since isopen = false
                    'close' => '17:00', //Not used since isopen = false
                )
        );
```

Comment: That isn't "sorting" the array, it's "merging" array entries, and there isn't any built-in function that will do it for you, so you'll basically need to loop through the array checking the values and merging them manually

Comment: I guess I could answer your question, but... you posted var_dumped data which I can't just grab, paste in my IDE and play with... and I'm too lazy to convert it back to php. Sorry.

Comment: Exactly what @georg said, I think I have an answer to this but in order for us to help you, you have to help us help you, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Sure, I added it now. My intentions were not no make you guys write it for me, but of course i would like to see your code! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
$newArray = array();
$dayCount = -1;
foreach ($days as $day) {
    if ( ($dayCount < 0) || 
         ($day['isopen'] != $newArray[$dayCount]['isopen']) || 
         ($day['open'] != $newArray[$dayCount]['open']) || 
         ($day['close'] != $newArray[$dayCount]['close']) ) {
        $newArray[++$dayCount] = array_merge(
            $day,
            array('dayTo' => '')
        );
    } else {
        $newArray[$dayCount]['dayTo'] = $day['day'];
    }
}
var_dump($newArray);
```

**EDIT**

From your posted initial array, this gives:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["day"]=>
    string(6) "Monday"
    ["isopen"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["open"]=>
    string(5) "10:00"
    ["close"]=>
    string(5) "17:00"
    ["dayTo"]=>
    string(6) "Friday"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["day"]=>
    string(8) "Saturday"
    ["isopen"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["open"]=>
    string(5) "10:00"
    ["close"]=>
    string(5) "17:00"
    ["dayTo"]=>
    string(6) "Sunday"
  }
}
```

If you have mismatched `open` and `close` values on "closed" days, then changing the `if` condition to

```
if ( ($dayCount < 0) || 
     ($day['isopen'] != $newArray[$dayCount]['isopen']) || 
     ($day['isopen'] && (($day['open'] != $newArray[$dayCount]['open']) || 
                         ($day['close'] != $newArray[$dayCount]['close']) ))) {
```

might help

Comment: I love this solution. It does not, how ever, "group" the closed days. That is, it gets 3 values in the array, when it should be 2 values; "dayTo" should be "sunday" on "saturday". Otherwise this is brilliant.

Comment: My test run did give `dayTo` of "sunday" on "saturday" from your posted array.

Answer (score 1):

That is tricky, but not that impossible (and be aware it is a sort of merging rather than sorting):

```
    $sorted = array();
    foreach($days as $k=>$v){

        $current = array(
            'open'=>$v['open'],
            'close'=>$v['close'],
            'isopen'=>$v['isopen'],
        );              

        if (empty($sorted) || $previous != $current ) {
            $sorted[] = array('firstDay'=>$k,'open'=>$v['open'],'close'=>$v['close']);
        } else
            $sorted[count($sorted)-1]['lastDay'] = $k;


        $previous = $current;   
    }

    print_r($sorted);
```